# How to achieve different animation while navigating to the same fragment with BottomNavigationView and navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-navigation

I have the below screens:

```
Bottom Navigation stack:       [A]               [B]
Root fragments:           [HomeFragment], [SettingsFragment]
Nested fragments:                         [ProfileFragment]
```

I want to achieve different animation while navigating to ProfileFragment:

1. From SettingsFragment
2. From BottomNavigationView going from ProfileFragment to [A] (HomeFragment) and then back to [B] (ProfileFragment)

I am using navigation component alongside bottomNavigationView which supports multiple backstack.
While navigating to ProfileFragment from SettingsFragment, I am using the below transition animations in the navigation graph:

```
app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_right"
app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_left"
```

Everything is working fine, but I don't want to use slide_right animation when the user goes to HomeFragment and then goes back to the ProfileFragment via bottomNavigationView.

I am setting up the navController like so:

```
bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Is there any way to have a different animation (e.g fade in, fade out) while navigating to ProfileFragment via bottomNavigationView but use my custom slide_right animation while navigating from SettingsFragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, downgrading navigation component version
from 2.5.3 to 2.5.0 did the trick for me.
Without any further change, it started to work as expected.